# Before_action method "Filter chain halted as :route rendered or redirected" . in Application Controller Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, redirect

In a `before_action`, I am checking if a user is logged in. If the user is already logged in then I check their role and redirect them to specific url according to their role.

But i have an issue that states:

> Filter chain halted as :route rendered or redirected

My code is

```
def route     
   if user_signed_in?       
    redirect_to '/admin/admins/dashboard' if current_user.admin?       
    redirect_to '/parent/parents/dashboard' if current_user.parent?       
    redirect_to '/mosque/mosques/dashboard' if current_user.mosque?    
   else       
    redirect_to '/users/sign_in'     
   end
end
```

Please help me I am stuck since last day.

Comment: I have 3 name spaces of  "parents", "mosque" and "admin". I want to redirect them to their specific name  space if they try to reach any other role's name space.

Comment: Are you using devise?

Comment: yes. I am using devise

Comment: What's the issue? Is a request being halted that you think shouldn't be? (If so then provide details of what that is)

Comment: i already mentioned the error. IF i user "redirect_to"  it say chain halted rendered or redirect.
But when I remove "redirect_to" it doesn't redirect to related name space. Like Id admin then it should take user to admin's dash board. And should not be able to give access to any other name space.

Comment: can a user be two roles at the same time of admin, parent, mosque?

Answer (score 0):

You're using devise for authentication ? Can you provide the error stack trace and the code where you call your route method?

Otherwise don't append code into your method after a redirection ...

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :route_user

  private

  def route_user
    target_path = '/users/sign_in'      
    if user_signed_in?       
      target_path =  '/admin/admins/dashboard' if current_user.admin?       
      target_path =  '/parent/parents/dashboard' if current_user.parent?       
      target_path =  '/mosque/mosques/dashboard' if current_user.mosque?
    end    
    redirect_to target_path
  end
end
```

Comment: after sign in.  admin goes to '/admin/admins/dashboard'. 
But when i access '/parent/parents/dashboard'. it goes to that url. I want to prevent it. But when i use redirect_to it gives that error.

Comment: when i use  "redirect_to" it gives this error.
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/admin/admins/dashboard
Filter chain halted as :route rendered or redirected.
BUt when i dont use it. Then admin can access to parent or masque name space. I dont want them to go any other role's name space.

Answer (score -1):

Simply add a 'and return' to each of the links:

```
def route     
   if user_signed_in?       
    redirect_to '/admin/admins/dashboard' and return if current_user.admin?       
    redirect_to '/parent/parents/dashboard' and return if current_user.parent?       
    redirect_to '/mosque/mosques/dashboard' and return if current_user.mosque?    
   else       
         redirect_to and return '/users/sign_in'     
   end
end
```

However, as a side note I'd be tempted to refactor this to be:

```
def route     
     redirect_to current_user.dashboard_url and return if user_signed_in?
     redirect_to '/users/sign_in'     
end
```

You'd then need to add a method in user model called dashboard_url which would return the relevant url

Comment: I want to confine every user to their namespace. SO that they would not be able to access others.

Comment: if user is not signed in it redirect correctly to "/users/sign_in". But for example when admin  logged in and want to access "parent/parents/dashboard" it goes to if part.  And gives error of chain halted .
but when i removes redirect_to then admin accesses other role's name spaces.